# ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function

Tags: arduino-mega, c++

This question comes on the heels of [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29115/how-can-i-move-these-global-variables-to-be)

In the last question I learned how to use an initializer list to solve my issue, but working with `ros::Subscriber` is requiring a different solution.

I'm dealing with a callback in this scenario. If I leave the callback as a standalone function then the program runs but I have no access to class members and methods inside the function which defeats the purpose. Here is my standalone callback:

```
void setPRYCallback( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg) {}
```

Once I move this into my class is when I encounter the error.

*steps to implementing into class*

```
// add member variable for callback
protected:
  void setPRYCallback( const std_msgs::Empty& );

...

// ass method
void ROSController::setPRYCallback( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg) {}

...

// set initializer list
ROSController::ROSController() : sub("setPRY", &setPRYCallback )
```

How do I thwart this error while keeping my callback as a class method?

**Program with Standalone Function Callback** *(program runs)*

```
#include <ros.h> // https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/jade-devel/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ros.h
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>

class ROSController {
  protected:
    ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub;
    ros::NodeHandle _nh;
  public:
    void loop();
    ROSController();
};

void setPRYCallback( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg) {}

ROSController::ROSController()  {
  this->_nh.initNode();
  this->_nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void ROSController::loop() {
  this->_nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

**Program with Method Callback** *(program fails)*

```
#include <ros.h> // https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/jade-devel/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ros.h
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>

class ROSController {
  protected:
    ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub;
    ros::NodeHandle _nh;
    void setPRYCallback( const std_msgs::Empty& );
  public:
    void loop();
    ROSController();
};

void ROSController::setPRYCallback( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg) {}

ROSController::ROSController() : sub("setPRY", &setPRYCallback )  {
  this->_nh.initNode();
  this->_nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void ROSController::loop() {
  this->_nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

*arduino mega*

Comment: Is there somewhere we can see this "ros.h" library you are using?

Comment: This will do the trick: https://github.com/NimbRo/nimbro-op-ros/blob/master/src/nimbro/contrib/roscpp/include/ros/ros.h

Comment: Start by making "setPRYCallback" static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move the setPRUCallback function into your class you change the prototype (well, C++ changes the prototype) from:

```
void setPRYCallback( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg) {}
```

to:

```
void setPRYCallback( ROSController *this, const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg) {}
```

That is now not what the callback registering function expects, and so it breaks.

By making the method `static` it removes that `*this` parameter, but also means that the function can only access static data within your class (variables also marked `static`) and there is only one copy of the function (and `static` variables) shared between all instances of the class (maybe not what you want).

Answer (score 2):

If you define instance as a global value, how about to set callback with using lambda expression as variable of constructor.

```cpp
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>

class ROSController {
  protected:
    ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub;
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
  public:
    ROSController(void (*staticPRYCallback)(const std_msgs::Empty& msg));
    void begin();
    void loop();
    void setPRYCallback( const std_msgs::Empty& );
};

void ROSController::setPRYCallback(const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg) {}

ROSController::ROSController(void (*staticPRYCallback)(const std_msgs::Empty& msg))
  : sub("setPRY", staticPRYCallback )  {
}

void ROSController::begin() {
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void ROSController::loop() {
  nh.spinOnce();
}

ROSController rosController([](const std_msgs::Empty& msg){
  rosController.setPRYCallback(msg);
});

void setup() {
  rosController.begin();
}

void loop() {
  rosController.loop();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Reference (A post of my blog in Japanese)
https://asukiaaa.blogspot.com/2020/09/define-cpp-callback-for-class-value-with-using-lambda-as-a-variable.html